# Show image from a server's folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to show a image from a server's folder, image name is specified by Query string, query gives te userid and then a image from folder with userid is rerieved,
Now i gettiing nothing in imageViewer, it is always blank .
this the code behind i am using :-

```
       Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString("UserID") <> "" Then
        Dim UserID As String = Request.QueryString("UserID").ToString()
        Dim img As Image = Me.FindControl("ImageUser")
        img.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~\UserImages\" + UserID + ".png")
    End If

End Sub
```

I also tried this code :-

```
          Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString("UserID") <> "" Then
        Dim UserID As String = Request.QueryString("UserID").ToString()
        UserImg.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~\UserImages\" + UserID + ".png")
    End If
```

and this is my designer file :-

```
         <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UserPhoto.aspx.vb" Inherits="IslamicPartner_web.UserPhoto" %>

       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
         <title></title>
       </head>
         <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

       <asp:Image ID="ImageUser" runat="server" Height="489px" Width="703px" />

</div>
</form>
```

Where is the problem ?

Actually i want to view this in WebView in IOS app for user image , like Facebook 
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the rendered HTML in a browser (usually via "View Source" or similar), you will see that you are sending a URL of something like "C:\Inetpub\websitename\UserImages\userid.png". This is *not* what you want as the browser does not have access to your web server's disks. The problem is that you are using Server.MapPath inappropriately.

What you want instead is something more like:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~\UserImages\" & UserID & ".png")) Then
    img.ImageUrl = "\UserImages\" & UserID & ".png")
Else
    img.ImageUrl = "\UserImages\UserUnknown.png"
End If
```

Comment: I tried this but , there is no diffrent ... NO image in ImageView